# How to know if there is Internet when using Parse.com Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com to insert values to Class, but when I have no Internet, it shows Error Message.

So How can I fix that ?

Comment: Another approach (for anyone else seeing this) is to use `saveEventually`, which will save more or less immediately if there's an internet connection, or if not wait until a connection is available to save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using following method you cab check if there is Internet connection available

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni == null) {
        // There are no active networks.
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
    }
}
```

For this to work you'll need to add following lined to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```